# Is it possible to use fuzzy matching in an Elasticsearch filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I know how to use fuzzy searches such as Levenstein in Elasticsearch.  I also get the notion of filters.  But I can't seem to find and example of how to use fuzzy criteria in filters.

This is useful, for example, if one uses a match query to find all names that match **"Nature Canada"**, but a few hits sneak through that should not be there, for example:

**"World Wildlife Fund Canada / Fonds Mondial Pour la Nature Canada"**  should not be there, because the francophone name has "Nature Canada" in it. In this case, using Levenshtein from the start would not work, as the occasional occurrence of various bilingual names would be excluded.  The idea is to phrase match to be very inclusive at first, and then apply fuzzy matches to exclude any obvious mishits after each result has been returned.

Hope this question makes sense to you Elastic heads out there. :)

Comment: sorry i haven't quite understood the above example however you can filter on any query using the query_filter  :http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure your answer is correct even without trying it.  I will code it up tomorrow and let you know.